# add custom map points/venue/location and display direction in bing map for windows phone application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Any one know how to add custom map point/location (not pushpin) in Bing map and display route between custom point/location for windows phone application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between this "point/location" and a pushpin ?

Comment: @Abhijith there are nothing diffrence between point and location because in map location is as a point, and other pushpin is just display purpose but we can not do process ie. display route. so i have code for add Pushpin but not for add location. morever pushpin treat as local because we just put on map control but we need to add location in bing map..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found BING Map DataSource API to insert data and display route for same.

i have also refer below link

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#VenueMapsModule3

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a "location" to Bing Maps - a location simply identifies a position on the earth's surface using latitude/longitude coordinates (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.location.aspx) - therefore Bing Maps already recognises every possible "location" on the earth.

If you want to calculate a route between two locations (e.g. between the lat/lng coordinates (37.78,-122.42) and (32.716,-117.1617)) you can make a request to the Bing Maps Routes API as follows:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Routes?wp.0=37.78,-122.42&wp.1=32.716,-117.1617&key=BingMapsKey

You need to substitute "BingMapsKey" with a valid key obtained from http://www.bingmapsportal.com. More information on usage of the Routes API at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx. Once you've got the route returned, loop through the waypoints and create a MapPolyLine to add to the map.

Comment: i have below this link to add data-source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg585130.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MapPolyLine` to display routes between locations.

If you want a more detailed answer, then you will have to ask a more detailed question.
(Give me more details to what you are looking to do, and I will update my answer)

Comment: Hello Bryan Watts,
i have already tried with MapPolyLine but it just draw the line but i have to add location in bing map and display route as per current location. i have also tried with static map image and draw lines but it is not a good idea becuase i need also use gestures to zoom-in or out.

please let me know if any other query

Comment: What do you mean by "add location in bing map"? Do you want to display a pushpin on the map at a specific gps coordinate? You said you wanted to display a route... you have to use MapPolyLine to display the route.  If you want to calculate the route, then you can use the Route API that Alastair suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the record: Maybe this can work with custom pins:

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins5